# How do I 'pass down' CFLAGS to subdependencies in Cargo?

Tags: rust-cargo

Is there some magic that can be added to a dependency entry of `Cargo.toml` to specify environment variables (e.g., `CFLAGS`) or other context to be used when building the dependency (and *only* this dependency)?

Background: this is specifically for a case where a dependency crate is a wrapper/builder for a C-based API/package sqlite (i.e., `rusqlite`).  The as-is crate passes some arguments to the target C compiler that aren't supported.